# Are PHP Models ( MVC ) Specifically Designated for DB Interaction Only?

Tags: php

I am currently working on a personal project. The entire site is dynamic so I am requesting all sorts of information from the database on all pages. I noticed that I was duplicating specific code to display the data to the pages. A few examples would be applying `htmlspecialchars` to the data or iterating through to set image paths, etc.

What i am wondering is if this is a bad decision to make so I can course correct early on. Most internet resources have said that the controller manipulates while the model fetches, updates, inserts, etc. into db. BUT it just makes sense at least for me anyway to manipulate the output data via model since all pages will use it in the same way.

Comment: You also can have helper to provide some "helper" functionality, like cleaning input, managing redirects or urls formations.

Comment: At the moment i have an array helper that will set or sanitize the data being requested.

Comment: If all pages use your data the same way, you will have a very light controller, however it is mandatory to keep this layer of your application, for many reasons. For example, the day you decide to use your data differently, you will be happy to be able to do so. Moreover, in large applications, the people making the front end may not be the ones making the model on the backend, keeping both separated is the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

No. A model merely represents data, whether that came from a database, an XML file, a web service/API, or even just an array.

If you find yourself doing the same thing over, then it’s time to re-factor and DRY your code out. For things like sanitising data, you would normally have a presenter that takes your model, and returns it data sanitised however you wish. That way the model has its single responsibility (represent data), and your present had a single responsibility of transforming data.

Comment: This all only applies to setting the data or image paths for slideshows, etc. So for example i would fetch the slideshow data on every page ( different slideshows ) and i would have to iterate through setting image paths + sanitizing output. So i switched over to sanitizing and setting image paths within the model and now i just pass the data from model through controller to view without cleaning up the output on each page using the slideshow. I just didn't know if it was "bad practice"